# Unattended Ubuntu Server install preseed hangs at "[!] Select a language"

Tags: server, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 15.04 with packer.
But the installation hangs at the

`"[!] Select a language"`

prompt. I googled and added this to my preseed config:

```
# Continue the installation in the selected language?
pkgsel/ignore-incomplete-language-support=true
d-i localechooser/translation/warn-severe boolean true
d-i localechooser/translation/warn-light boolean true
```

But to no avail. Does anybody have an idea what else to try?

**Edit**

It works if I set all language related entries to en/us (this is the packer file):

```
    "debian-installer=en_US auto locale=en_US kbd-chooser/method=us ",
    "keyboard-configuration/modelcode=SKIP keyboard-configuration/layout=USA",
    "keyboard-configuration/variant=USA console-setup/ask_detect=false ",
```

so it's not so bad but I would prefer to have it continue the installation in the selected language.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the timeout for language selection is set to 0 (infinity) If I could somehow programatically edit that before the preseed is run that would be sufficient also.